# MongoDB perform $match with two input array values?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, I am trying to write a query where I have two input array `Bills`, `Names` where the first one contains billids and the second one contains names of the person. Also in reality Bills at index `i` and Names at index `i` is the actual document which we want to search in MongoDB.

I want to write a query such that `Bills[i] = db_billid && Names[i] = db_name` which means I want to return the result where at a particular index both billid and name matches.

I thought of using `$in` but the thing is I can apply `$in` in `Bills` but I don't know at which index that billid is found.

`{ $and: [{ billid: { $in: Bills } }, {name: Names[**index at which this bill is found]}] }`

Can anyone please help me how can I solve this ??

**MongoDB** Schema

```
var transactionsschema = new Schema({
    transactionid: {type: String},
    billid: {type: String},
    name: {type: String}
});
```

**Sample documents in MongoDB**

```
{ _id: XXXXXXXXXXX, transactionid: 1, billid : bnb1234, name: "sudhanshu"}, { _id: XXXXXXXXXXX, transactionid: 2, billid : bnb1235, name: "michael"}, { _id: XXXXXXXXXXX, transactionid: 3, billid : bnb1236, name: "Morgot"}
```

**Sample arrays**

```
Bills = ["bill1", "bill2", "bill3"], Names = ["name1", "name2", "name"]
```

**Edit** - If $in can work in array of objects then I can have array of object with keys as billid and name

> var arr = [{ billid: "bill1", "name": "name1"}, {billid: "bill2", "name": "name2"}, {billid: "bill3", "name": "name3"}]

But the thing is then how can put below query

`{ $and: [{ billid: { $in: arr.Bills } }, {name: arr.Names}] }`

Comment: Could you add sample document and sample Bills and Name ?

Comment: @mickl wait let me add it.

Comment: @mickl I have added sample docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing that `bills` are unique but `names` may have duplicates you can use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to get index of matching `bill` and then use that index to compare `names` array at evaluated index (using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt) to retrieve value). Also you have to check if value returned by `$indexOfArray` is not equal to `-1` (no match)

```
var bills = ["bnb1234", "bnb1235"];
var names = ["sudhanshu", "michael"];

db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $and: [
                    { $ne: [{ $indexOfArray: [ bills, "$billid" ] }, -1] },
                    { $eq: ["$name", { $arrayElemAt: [ names, { $indexOfArray: [ bills, "$billid" ] } ] }] },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

alternatively [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) can be used to avoid duplication:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { index: { $indexOfArray: [ bills, "$billid" ] } },
                    in: { $and: [ { $ne: [ "$$index", -1 ] }, { $eq: [ "$name", { $arrayElemAt: [ names, "$$index" ] }] }]}
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Suppose I have two nested queries first one is mine and the second one whose solution you have given, like `$match: {$and: { "transactionid": "12345678"}, { Your Query} }, now will it work ? Is this rightly nested or not?

Comment: You can add more conditions to `$match`, like `{
    $and: [
        { $ne: ["$billIndex", -1] },
        { $ne: ["$nameIndex", -1] },
        { $eq: ["$billIndex", "$nameIndex"] },
        { $eq: [ "$transactionId": 123 ] }
    ]
}` is that what you mean ?

Comment: Leave it, just wanted to ask as `Bills` are unique fields but `Names` are not so, suppose Sample DB is `[{ billid : bnb1234, name: "michael"}, {billid : bnb1235, name: "michael"}]` `Bills = ["bnb1234", "bnb1235"]` and `Names = ["michael", "michael"]` Now the thing here is that when you will use `$match` to see index of both of them then for first one Names index will be `1` and Bills index will be `1` so it's a match but for the second one as Bills index is `2` but Names index is `1`, not `2`(`because Names are not unique`).

Comment: So how can I overcome that thing. Btw thanks for helping me out of here just one line close to the solution :)

Comment: Just found the solution :) changed your answer a bit, thanks a lot man. I have mentioned the solution in the post, change your answer here so that I can accept it (y).

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur just edited my answer which can be a way easier if you use arrayElemAt. Check my edited answer

Comment: Your query is returning all fields with `name` `michael` but it should only return two docs.

Comment: Both solution is kind of the same, you just not used addFields, When we addFields does it make query bit slow ? Because even inside your query when you will use `names` and `bills` it will also imply the same thing ?

Comment: Thanks bdw without you it wasn't possible :)